# How to authenticate different types of models in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have 2 types of users that can log in to the system. The first is `User` and the other is `Author`. However, I can only check the roles of `User` on my `SecurityConfig` class. I'm stuck because I don't know what to search for and how to improve.

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user/create")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/**")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/admin/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/author/**")
                .hasRole("AUTHOR")
                .anyRequest()
                .denyAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            final User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
            List<String> roleList = user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> role.getName().name()).toList();
            return new MyUserDetails(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), roleList);
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see my `userDetailsService` function is checking only the User class.

The only solution I can do is using try-catch

```java
@Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        return username -> {
            try {
                final User user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
                List<String> roleList = user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> role.getName().name()).toList();
                return new MyUserDetails(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), roleList);
            } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
                final Author author = authorService.findAuthorByUsername(username);
                List<String> roleList = author.getRoles().stream().map(role -> role.getName().name()).toList();
                return new MyUserDetails(author.getUsername(), author.getPassword(), roleList);
            }
        };
    }
```

But I feel it isn't the best approach and Spring has a better solution.

You may also want to look at `MyUserDetails` class, there is nothing special about it I belive but here it is

```java
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public MyUserDetails(String username, String password, List<String> roles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So, what do I need to do or learn to get this function to check the entities in the author table without using extra things? Because with my solution, if there were 50 types of users the code will be so ugly.

Comment: You don't have 2 types of users.  You have users (i.e. an authenticated entity using your system) and 3 roles: `ADMIN`, `AUTHOR`, and `USER`.  Don't put your users in different collections (or tables if you're using a relational database).  Add a `roles` property to your user entity and store the users in one collection (table).  When you load the user in your `DetailsService` the correct `roles` will be set when the entity is unmarshalled.

Comment: The design you suggested was actually the first version of my application, but I couldn't figure out how to separate the field differences between User-Author entities. While there are fields for the user in the database such as the user's identity information, username, password, and books he read, there are only e-mail, password, and books he wrote for the author. While User and Author have different fields, frankly, I couldn't design in my mind to put them in the same class. Do you have an opinion on this subject?

Comment: Oh I always have opinions...they may not be right however. :D  `User` is going to be the base entity.  (oops hit enter, sorry if you saw the unfinished comment)  `Author` can extend `User` and have a field `booksAuthored`. The exact implementation somewhat depends on the type of database, relational vs document. In a relational DB you'll query  'users' table and left join on 'books' table to populate the `Author` entity. It's generally better to denormalize in a document store so it would be ok if `booksAuthored` was stored in the `users` collection.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I don't know if it's the best, but I'm sure it's excellent. As you said, I created a superclass and when I inherited the author and the user from this class, Spring magically set the whole database for it. I really didn't know that Spring was that smart. Right now everything is great and works as I want.

Comment: another thing just to point out, if you dont want to throw an exception when fetching users you can return a `Optional<User>` from `userService.getUserByUsername(username);` and either use `IfPresent` or `map` and `orElse` to handle things.